# Java Streams - how to Sum Values if other fields match

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a list of objects for example:

```
Part("12345" , "Part1", 5));
Part("67890" , "Part5", 2));
Part("12345" , "Part1", 2));
```

I want to be able to convert to the below list, whereby if the part number appears once with the quantities summed.

Result

```
Part("12345" , "Part1", 7));
Part("67890" , "Part5", 2));

return emptyIfNull(partList.getParts())
           .stream()
            .map(part -> Part
                    .builder()
                    .partNumber(part.getNumber())
                    .partDescription(part.getDescription())
                    .partQuantity(part.getQuantity()) // WHAT CHANGE DO I NEED TO MAKE TO FILTER AND SUM
                    .build())
            .collect(toList());
```

Comment: Hi, I think you need to group the parts by part number, summing the quantities for each part number... so you can obtain a list where the quantities are summed for each unique part number.

Comment: Instead of that `map` operation, [collect the parts to a map](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)) with the number as the key, the part as the value, and an appropriate "merge function". Then copy the resulting map's values into a list to return from the method. You can use `Collectors::collectingAndThen` to do both steps in a single collect operation if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the value `Part` represented as following:

```
record Part(String number, String description, int quantity) {
    private Part merge(Part another) {
        return new Part(this.number, this.description,
                this.quantity + another.quantity);
    }
}
```

you can collect the list of *merged* values using the `toMap` collector such as:

```
Collection<Part> mergedValues = emptyIfNull(partList.getParts())
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> p.number, 
                Function.identity(), Part::merge))
        .values();
```